# Can I add 2 values inside cell of datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I know this sound absurd. How can a cell have two values? Well, that's the problem I need to solve. One value will be text and another one will be an image.

### Background:

I need to generate the datagridview and display the row and column number in the heading.
Datagridview cell values will be images. I also need to reference that image on the cell itself.
**E.g.** If the image is of a dog then "dog" text should appear above the image. I already have data of text respective images.

### My thought on this:

As a cell can not have two values simultaneously and I can't concate the text and image, what I thought is dividing the row into two rows and achieving that. But I am not sure this is feasible as it will change the row and column count.

I am seeking help with another approach to achieve this.

Comment: There is only one `Value` property, so no, not from that perspective. You can create custom columns and cells and have them behave any way you want though. If you want to display an image and some text then have at it. They won't both be assigned to the `Value` property though.

Comment: How can a custom cell have 2 values then? Cell.Value property will be referenced for the image only not the text. Based on the condition I need to change it. For e.g. if you consider the example given in the question, based on the condition I need to change an image of a white dog from a black dog.

Comment: You can add whatever properties you want to a custom cell. You could have a `Text` property and use `Value` for the image, or use `Value` for the text and have an `Image` property or use two custom properties or require the `Value` to be an object with two properties. It's a custom cell so you decide how it works.

Comment: but I can't show both text and image in the cell. right?

Comment: You can show whatever you want to show in a custom cell. There's no standard cell type that will allow you to display both. If you're not editing the text, one option could be to create a new `Bitmap` and draw the original image and the text onto that and then display it in a standard image column.